# Why can't I change the ViewController?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

My application have 2 view controllers called Accueil and Menu in the Storyboard called Main
Where I click to a button placed in accueil, it prints "entered here" but it does NOT change the view controller... Why ? Please help me

```
@IBAction func goTuMenu(sender: UIButton) {
    let story = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let menu = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Menu")
    navigationController?.showViewController(menu, sender: self)
    print("entered here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have a `UINavigationController` in your storyboard.

Check out the following line of code:

```
navigationController?.showViewController(menu, sender: self)
```

There is a `?` after `navigationController` because a navigation controller may not exist in the hierarchy if you have not put one there.

In the Storyboard, you should embed your first view controller inside a [navigation controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html), and then the second should be connected to the first, forming a chain. You should probably also be creating segues in the Storyboard, though it's not required.

What you are trying to do, however, sounds like it could be the job for a [`UITabBarController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW1) instead, which can also be found in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually changing view on button click, simply drag with right click from button to second view and select show. You can still have action made and you can do printing there.

[image]